# .NET SQL Server UDF Windowing

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, user-defined-functions, sqlclr

Is it possible to create a C# SQL Server UDF that can perform functions similar to the built-in Windowing functions?

For example, I'd like to write a function that will calculate a moving average. The only documentation I'm finding for .NET UDF's, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx), shows a simple input of a single value.

However, for my 50-day moving average, I would need the value from each row, and the preceding 49.

Comment: Why not write a stored procedure on the database, itself?

Comment: @StanShaw That's where I started.  Eventually I'm going to expand this out to quite a few calculations for technical analysis of stock market data, and I had read that it was a bad choice to do that in T-SQL, and that .NET UDF's would be better.  However, it didn't give any examples of said UDF's.

Comment: What was the reason you read that stored procedures are a bad choice?

Comment: You can create a SQLCLR aggregate function. But, only the partition by clause is supported. This won't really help you with your rolling average, though, since you can calculate average without needing to invoke the CLR.

Comment: what version of SQL are you on?

Comment: @StanShaw It was an answer of another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002330/how-to-do-trading-technical-analysis-calculations-in-sql-server).  He didn't give any particular reason, other than previous experience.  After writing a stored procedure to calculate Exponential Moving Average, that required a Cursor, and having the execution take an unacceptable amount of time, I thought he might be correct and began looking into UDFs.

Comment: @MatthewWhited SQL Server 2012

Comment: if you aren't on 2012 you could use a CTE to create a value that can be used with the standard windowing operations as the PARTITION key.

Comment: http://tomaslind.net/2013/10/22/moving-average-in-t-sql/

Comment: @Boone There is absolutely no reason why you would need a cursor to do what you're asking, so I'm either missing something or the poster wasn't that strong with SQL.  If you want an average for the last 50 days, it's as simple as select avg(ColumnName) from TableName where DateField >= DateAdd(d, -50, getdate())

Comment: I didn't say anything about cursors.  I did say he could use a CTE if he can't use windowing functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL 2012 or above you can use the `ROWS PRECEDING` option with `AVG`

```
SELECT 
    AVG([your column]) OVER (
        ORDER BY [your date] 
        ROWS BETWEEN 50 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [Rolling 50 Day Average]
FROM [your table]
```

As for using an SQLCLR UDF with windowing it looks like the only supported feature is `PARTITION BY`

[Is it possible to use user defined aggregates (clr) with window functions (over)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352026/is-it-possible-to-use-user-defined-aggregates-clr-with-window-functions-over)

Comment: I understand the way to do a simple moving average in T-SQL.  I'm wondering if it can be replicated in a .NET UDF, though.

Comment: in SQLCLR it would have to take table valued parameters.  i think those only work with stored procs.

Comment: It looks like the answer is no.  Not in a UDF.

Comment: Why not just say where [your date] >= dateadd(d, -50, getdate())?  Is there a performance difference?  Also, doesn't your answer assume that there cannot be more than one record per day - and if there is more than one record, the average would be incorrect, since it only grabs the last 50 records, not the last 50 days worth of records?

Comment: that's not the same thing.  unless you are doing a recursive CTE (which is shown in the example I linked in the comments up top... http://tomaslind.net/2013/10/22/moving-average-in-t-sql/ )

Comment: BTW, the performance of doing a recursive CTE to build the moving average is orders of magnitude worse than using the above windowing function.